# How do I use variables in canJS?

Tags: javascript, canjs

Here is the code I am trying to play around with. 
In my JS file I have:
$count = 0

In my HTML I am trying:

```html
{{#if categories}}
<div id="categories">
  {{#each categories}}
  {{count = count + 1}}
  <div class="category" url="{{url}}">
    <div class="category-icon"></div>
    <div class="category-name">{{name}}</div>
    <span class="category-info"></span>
  </div>
  {{#if !(count%3)}}
  <br/>
 {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

I want there to be a new line after every three categories I display - is there a way to do this with canJS?

Comment: I don't know anything about CanJs, but I think you're going to need to reset `count` in that if-statement, or use a modulus operator to check if it's divisible by 3.

Comment: Haha thank you, that is true, I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a simple helper `everyThird` and use `@index` helper provided with stache engine. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23g16d1v/).

```
helpers: {
    everyThird: function(val) {
        return val && val%3 === 0;
    }
}
```

inside template

```
  <ul>
  {{#each categories}}
    {{#if everyThird(@index)}}
     <li><hr></li>
    {{/if}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>    
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Comment: I am editing a Zendesk template, so I don't have @index :(

Comment: @keyan.r I'm not familiar with "Zendesk" and its limitations but if they internally use handlerbars there should be `@index` helper. http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Comment: Ah, ok, yes this works. However, where do I implement the "helpers:"? Again, in Zendesk I only have access to modify html, css, and javascript on a template ~ which one of these files would I put the "helpers:" you wrote?

Comment: I think you need js file. :) But really don't know which one.